# nginx with php-fpm location settings

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Many of the guides for setting up Wordpress (or similar applications) on nginx with php-fpm use a configuration that in part looks something like this:

```
 location    ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
              fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
              if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                #some guides suggest try_files $uri =404; instead
                return 404;
              }
              fastcgi_pass php;
              fastcgi_index index.php;
              include fastcgi_params;
  }

  #Route anything not otherwise matched
  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }
```

With this configuration if the requested URI `/someuri` isn't an actual location it'll get routed to `index.php` and from there to the backend.

The `404` part is there to prevent unauthorized code execution, so if the requested URI is `/somefile.php` which doesn't exist then a simple nginx `404` is generated.

What would be a better way to configure this (& remain 'secure') so that a request for a nonexistant php file also get passed to the backend via `index.php`?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

Comment: @MichaelHampton, thanks, that is one of the many guides I've looked at.

Comment: Not sure to understand...a request to a non-existant php file should even not be passed to the backend (imho - or i've missed something). Why do you want this behaviour ?

Comment: @krisFR, FPM shouldn't try to execute the non-existant file. It should execute `index.php` which has error handling and other functions that are able to deal with the request.

Comment: hum...have you tried to remove the `if` statement ?

Comment: @krisFR doing that could allow unauthorized code execution.

Comment: I still cannot understand why you want this behaviour. `It should execute index.php which has error handling and other functions that are able to deal with the request` is not an answer to this as it seems this `index.php` failed in denying unauthorized code execution. Also, as you said : `Many of the guides for setting up Wordpress...use a configuration...like this` Don't you think there is a **real** reason behind this ? Sorry, not clear to me why you want this

Comment: @krisFR, The main thing I don't want is the plain Nginx error page. index.php is a front controller that already has the logic to display a 404 page or whatever, but it's no good if it's code is never executed. (which with the given config won't happen -- with or without the if statement.)